# Adding custom button to PE SDK UI

Tags: java, android, photoeditorsdk

I have some trouble to find information how to extend default PhotoEditor SDK. I need to add a button to default UI panel where cancel and accept buttons are located. Is there any way to do this?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

1. Extend the View Class ly.img.android.ui.widgets.ImgLyTitleBar
2. Overload this layout (this means, put this layout it in your Application res folder without rename it) and replace ly.img.android.ui.widgets.ImgLyTitleBar with your class.
   https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-android-demo/blob/master/default_res_files/res/layout/imgly_activity_photo_editor.xml
3. Add your button, by overload this layout
   https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-android-demo/blob/master/default_res_files/res/layout/imgly_widget_actionbar.xml
4. Add your button logic, in your ImgLyTitleBar extending class.

Best,
Sven

Comment: Thank you very much! It was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. I want to get image that is currently in editor in onClickListener method of this new custom button. I discovered that PESDK has R.id.editorImageView. I do this: `((View) MyCustomExtensionOfImgLyTitleBar.this.getParent()).findViewById(ly.img.android.R.id.editorImageView)` . But that returns instance of EditorPreview class that couldn't be cast to ImageView. And I found no methods to get image. Also I discovered R.id.image and R.id.action_image. But this doesn't relate to current, that is undo button as I got. Thank you.